# Lemma 8.1 of "The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2)"

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory, local-field, profinite-groups, haar-measure

Let $F$ be a non-Archimedean local field, and $N$ the subgroup of $G=GL_2(F)$ of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ with $x \in F$. Let $(\pi,V)$ be a smooth representation of $N$, and $\mu_N$ a Haar measure on N. Consider the linear subspace $V(N)$ of $V$ generated by vectors of the form $\pi(n)v-v$ with $n \in N, v \in V$.

My question concerns the following equivalence: a vector $v \in V$ is also in $V(N)$ if and only if there exists a compact open subgroup $N_0$ of $N$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{N_0}\pi(n)v\, d\mu_N(n)=0.
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

The textbook (The Local Langlands for GL(2) - Bushnell, Henniart) I'm using offers the following proof:

Recall $N \cong F$ as groups and $F$ is the union of an ascending sequence of compact open subgroups. Now assume $v \in V(N)$, that is, there exists $n_1,\dots,n_r \in N$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^{r} \pi(n_i)v_i-v_i=v.
\end{equation*}
By the above, we can find a compact open subgroup $N_0$ of $N$ that contains $n_1,\dots,n_r$. The above integral is zero for this choice of $N_0$.

For the converse direction, let $v \in V$ and suppose there is a compact open subgroup $N_0$ of $N$
such that the above integral equality holds. Then there exists a normal open subgroup $N_1$ of $N_0$ with $v \in V^{N_1}=\{v \in V:\pi(n)v=v\, \forall n \in N_1 \}$. The space $V^{N_1}$ carries a representation of the finite group $N_0/N_1$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
V^{N_1}=V^{N_1}(N_0/N_1) \oplus V^{N_0}
\end{equation}
and the map
\begin{equation}
\omega \mapsto \mu_N(N_0)^{-1} \int_{N_0}\pi(n)v\, d\mu_N(n)
\end{equation}
is the $N_0$-projection $N_1 \rightarrow N_0$. This has kernel $V^{N_1}(N_0/N_1) \subset V(N)$ so we are done.

My questions:

(1) When they claim $F$ is the union of an ascending sequence of compact open subgroups do they explicitly mean that $F=\bigcup_{i \geq 1} p^{-i}\mathfrak{o}$ where $\mathfrak{o}$ is the discrete valuation ring of $F$, and $p$ is the characteristic of $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ ($\mathfrak{p}$ being the maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$)?

(2) After choosing $N_0$ as above, I compute the integral to the following point:
\begin{align*}
\int_{N_0}\pi(n)v\, d\mu_N(n)&= \int_{N_0}\pi(n)(\sum_{i=1}^{r} \pi(n_i)v_i-v_i)\, d\mu_N(n) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{r} \int_{N_0} (\pi(nn_i)v_i-\pi(n)v_i)\, d\mu_N(n).
\end{align*}
It's not clear to me why this is zero.

(3) In the converse direction of the proof, I don't see why $N_1$ should exist with $v \in V^{N_1}$.

Comment: For your question 1) yes if $F$ has characteristic $0$ (ie. a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$) no if $F$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$ (in which case simply replace $p$ by $t$).

Comment: For 2), where does the $\pi(n_i)$ come from in the RHS of your last equality? For 3), I think that smooth representations are those where any vector has an open stabilizer – which should solve your issue.

Comment: @Mindlack: There was a typo in my computations of (2), I have fixed these now.

Comment: For 2), then, you can assume $r=1$, and use the fact that $\mu_N$ is Haar.

Comment: @Mindlack: Can you elaborate on your final answer. I am new to working with Haar measure and cannot see how the argument goes.

Comment: As $\mu_N$ is Haar, for any $L^1$ function $f$ on $N$, and any $t \in N$, $\int_N{f(tn)d\mu_N(n)}=\int_N{f(n)d\mu_N(n)}$. Apply this to $f(x)=1_{x \in N_0}\pi(x)v_i$ (and remember $N$ is abelian).

Comment: @Mindlack: It's clear now, thanks for the help!